# Select the manager name with the most employees

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a table emp with columns empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno

I have tried

```
SELECT m.ename, COUNT(e.empno) FROM emp e
INNER JOIN emp m ON e.empno = m.empno
GROUP BY m.ename HAVING COUNT(e.empno) = GREATEST(COUNT(e.empno));
```

My output is the names of the managers each with the value 1
How do we output the name of the manager with the most employees?

Comment: in which column you have the manager and how can we identify the manager of an employee?

Comment: Your query has the potential error that two employees have the same same but different names. Your query will count them as the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the `ON` clause.  Second, Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` if you want one row:

```
SELECT m.ename, COUNT(e.empno)
FROM emp e INNER JOIN
     emp m
     ON m.empno = e.mgr
GROUP BY m.ename
ORDER BY COUNT(e.empno) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your `HAVING` clause does not filter anything because any (non-NULL) value is equal to itself.

Comment: This returns the wrong manager in the correct format. Thanks for inspiring my answer below, it returns the correct manager. Cheers

Comment: Limit as a solution will always be error prone: you might have more than one tuple that have the exact same number of maximum counts.

Comment: @dmg . . . The question is **singular**:  "Select the manager name with the most employees".  This selects one manager, consistent with the question.

Comment: @ModelNaoe . . . I fixed the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are no constraints that force that there is one manager with the most employees. What if two managers have _exactly_ the same number of employees (the maximum)? For example, the company has only two managers, and each manager has 10 employees?

Comment: @dmg . . . That's nice.  That is not the question that is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.empno), m.ename FROM emp e
INNER JOIN emp m ON e.mgr = m.empno
GROUP BY m.ename HAVING GREATEST(COUNT(e.ename)) = COUNT(e.ename)
LIMIT 1;
```